# LINQ to SQL help needed

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am pretty new to LINQ to SQL and trying to write the following query in LINQ. Can somebody please guide me how to write it in LINQ.

```
Select  app.ApplicationGenID, max(appHis.ApplicationStatusHistoryGenID), max  (appHis.ApplicationStatusGenID)
from Application app
join Applicant appl on app.ApplicantGenId = appl.ApplicantGenID
Left Outer Join ApplicationStatus appStatus on app.ApplicationGenID = appStatus.ApplicationGenID
Where appl.ClientID=4 and (app.IsDeleted=0 or app.IsDeleted is null)
Group By app.ApplicationGenID
```

Comment: do you having any error? also my guess is vb.net?

Comment: If not error you should detail what is your expected result.

Comment: I am not getting error but not able to get the desired result. As you can see in above query that I am trying to join three tables. Application and Applicant table will have inner join. While I want all rows from Application table and only matching rows from ApplicationStatus table. Also ApplicationStatus table can have multiple rows so we need to get the value of last row from that table.

Comment: if you have this in db the best way to solve is try to write the query in sql first. Also you can load the schema and data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ that way we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't see from your SQL query where did you get `appHis` table.

But your **LinQ** in *extension method syntax* should look like this if you have keys on your tables:

```
  var res = _context.Applicant
                .Where(x => x.ClientID == 4 
                    && (x.Application.IsDeleted == 0 || x.Application.IsDeleted == null))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationGenID)
                    .Select(x => new 
                    {
                        ApplicationGenID = x.Key,
                        //Not sure about next 2 lines, couse i don't know where you get appHis
                        ApplicationStatusHistoryGenID = x.Max(y => y.ApplicationStatusHistoryGenID),
                        ApplicationStatusGenID = x.Max(y => y.ApplicationStatusGenID)
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys. This is how I ended up doing it. Putting it here for future reference.

```
var result = (from app in context.Application
                                join appl in context.Applicant on new {ApplicantGenId = app.ApplicantGenId} equals
                                    new {ApplicantGenId = appl.ApplicantGenID}
                                join appStatus in context.ApplicationStatus on app.ApplicationGenID equals
                                    appStatus.ApplicationGenID into appStatus_join
                                from appStatus in appStatus_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join refStatus in context.ref_ApplicationStatus on appStatus.ApplicationStatusGenID
                                    equals refStatus.ApplicationStatusGenID into refStatus_join
                                from refStatus in refStatus_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where
                                    appl.ClientID == 4 &&
                                    (app.IsDeleted == false ||
                                     app.IsDeleted == null)
                                group new {app, appStatus, refStatus} by new
                                {
                                    app.ApplicationGenID
                                }
                                into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    ApplicationGenID = (int?) g.Key.ApplicationGenID,
                                    ApplicationStatusGenID = (int?) g.Max(p => p.appStatus.ApplicationStatusGenID),
                                    ApplicationStatusDesc = g.Min(p => p.refStatus.ApplicationStatusDesc),
                                    ApplicationStatusDate = (DateTime?) g.Max(p => p.appStatus.StatusDate)
                                }).ToList();
```